# Angular with eslint on accessibility throws error

Tags: angular, eslint

I am trying to analysis accessibility issues using `eslint` with angular. But getting errors like this;

```
E:\Training\landing-app\src\app\app.component.spec.ts
  1:1  error  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/rule-name' was not found  jsx-a11y/rule-name

E:\Training\landing-app\src\app\app.component.ts
  1:1  error  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/rule-name' was not found  jsx-a11y/rule-name

E:\Training\landing-app\src\app\app.module.ts
  1:1  error  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/rule-name' was not found  jsx-a11y/rule-name

E:\Training\landing-app\src\app\news-api\na-article-list\na-article-list.component.spec.ts
  1:1  error  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/rule-name' was not found  jsx-a11y/rule-name
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "landing-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "eslint": "eslint",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn run lint",
      "pre-push": "yarn run lint && yarn test"
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "latest",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@briebug/jest-schematic": "4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "latest",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  },
  "jestSonar": {}
}
```

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "jsx-a11y"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "jsx-a11y/rule-name": 2,
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error states: a rule named `jsx-a11y/rule-name` does not exist. I suppose you copied this from their readme, but what they try to tell you is to replace `rule-name` with the name of an actual rule in the plugin.

As you already extend their recommended rule set, it should be enough to just remove the line referencing the not existing rule.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. i remove this line `"jsx-a11y/rule-name": 2,` But no lint result received. i have a image without an alt missing state.

Comment: I've never used the jsx-a11y eslint plugin and I don't know what exactly you're trying to achive, but it sounds like you're expecting a rule to be active that is currently not. The plugin's documentation lists all available rules and you just need to add them in your eslintrc as you did with `rule-name` but instead use the proper name.